# Contact Image Size

Tags: contacts, contact-image

Is there any way to resize the contact image, restrict the size/dimensions of the contact image upon upload, etc.

Using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 4.6.x

Thank you.

Currently we have some contact records with a huge uploaded image taking over 1/4 of the screen.

Comment: This [old forum thread on using CiviCRM, Views and Imagecache](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34929.0) is worth a look. The [performance advantages](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/795696d1e8b25b8b9130) of not serving contact images directly from CiviCRM make it extremely appealing, especially if you use CiviCRM images in a frequently viewed place (eg contributor headshots on the front page, like civicrm.org used to). You could even intercept the contact display image request at webserver level and redirect to a URL serviced by such a method.

Comment: @ChrisBurgess that comment would make a fine answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contact summary screen should automatically limit the image size to a maximum of 100px. If this is not working correctly you could add this to your site's css file:

```
.crm-contact_image img {
   max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This [forum thread from 2015 on using CiviCRM, Views and Imagecache](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34929.0) is worth a look.

There are some [performance gains in not serving contact images directly from CiviCRM](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/795696d1e8b25b8b9130) which might be worthwhile, especially if you use CiviCRM images in a frequently viewed place (eg contributor headshots on the front page, like civicrm.org used to).

I guess you could even intercept the contact display image request at webserver level and redirect to a URL serviced by such a method. (But Coleman's CSS is way easier, esp if it's the default for CiviCRM!)